# OpenGL: glGenVertexArrays() gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, glfw, exc-bad-access

When I use OpenGL and run my code to make a triangle the function glGenVertexArrays() gives me EXE_BAD_ACCESS

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n28UH.jpg)

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <cmath>

// Window specs
const int HEIGHT = 800;
const int WIDTH = 600;

// Shader source code
const char* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
"}\0";
const char* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   FragColor = vec4(0.8f, 0.3f, 0.02f, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";

int main(void)
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cout<<"GLFW failed to Initialize!"<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    
    
    GLfloat vertices[] =
    {
        -0.5f, -0.5f * float(sqrt(3)) / 3, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f * float(sqrt(3)) / 3, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.5f * float(sqrt(3)) * 2 / 3, 0.0f
    };
    
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Open GL", NULL, NULL);
        
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    
    if(!window)
    {
        std::cout<<"Something went Wrong when Creating a Window!\nShutting down ..."<<std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    //
    gladLoadGL();
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    
    GLuint fragmentShader  = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    //
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    
    GLuint VAO;
    GLuint VBO;
    
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I used glad to write the code. Does anybody have any idea how to fix this or what I did wrong.

To recreate it use Xcode 13.2.1 then link Glad using Opengl 4.1 and GLFW and make it look something like this

[File Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD99E.jpg)

Then paste the code into main and run.

Comment: No I used 4.1 so I'm going to delete the library and reinstall and see how it goes.

Comment: Why are you calling `glfwWindowHint()` *after* `glfwCreateWindow()`?

Comment: I double checked and I changed it 3.3 but no change. Also I use glfwWindowHint() after CreateWindow() because when I put it before I was getting error messages but when I moved them around it just worked. Idk why though?

Comment: Also, check that your shader compiled and linked.  Feel free to use [this](https://github.com/genpfault/glfw-mcve-base/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L8-L26) snippet for [that](https://github.com/genpfault/glfw-mcve-base/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L92-L97).

Comment: *"I use `glfwWindowHint()` after `glfwCreateWindow()` because when I put it before I was getting error messages .."* - !? `glfwWindowHint` affects how the window (OpenGL context) is created. However, it has not any effect after `glfwCreateWindow`

Comment: `glGenVertexArrays` requires OpenGL 3.0 or later.  Because you don't call `glfwWindowHint` until *after* you've created the window your context is probably only OpenGL 2.0 or 2.1.  Hence the problem.

Comment: I changed it but my window fails to be created when the window hint comes first.

Comment: @NickDeveloper Does your hardware support OpenGL 3.3 at all?

Comment: I'm using Mac and I have heard that OpenGl does not work on it but I'm confused how OpenGL 2.0 or whatever version I'm using is working but not OpenGL 3.3 is working correctly.

Comment: If window creation fails you need to check the error using [`glfwGetError`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro_guide.html#error_handling).

Comment: Note that with a 3.3 core profile on MacOS you may also need to call `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE)` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- `glfwWindowHint()` only affects the *next* `glfwCreateWindow()` call so make sure to call them before you create a window.  The default hint settings will generally give you a version 2.1 Compatibility context on macOS which won't be able to handle `#version 330 core` GLSL code.
- `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR` was used twice; you need a `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR` too.
- macOS needs `GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT` set to `GLFW_TRUE` for Core contexts.
- Check for shader compilation/link errors.
- Your GLAD might have been out of sync for the GL version you were targeting; see the generator link in the comments for the settings I used.
- GLFW has a perfectly usable `GLADloadproc` in `glfwGetProcAddress()`; might as well switch from `gladLoadGL()` to `gladLoadGLLoader()`.
- Supplying a `glfwSetErrorCallback()` can get you some early/immediate error reporting from GLFW.  It's how I discovered the missing `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR` hint.  No reason not to use it.

All together:

```
// g++ -Iinclude main.cpp src/glad.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs glfw3`

// Commandline:
//   --profile="compatibility" --api="gl=3.3" --generator="c" --spec="gl" --no-loader --extensions=""
// Online:
//   https://glad.dav1d.de/#profile=compatibility&language=c&specification=gl&api=gl%3D3.3
#include <glad/glad.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void CheckStatus( GLuint obj, bool isShader )
{
    GLint status = GL_FALSE, log[ 1 << 11 ] = { 0 };
    ( isShader ? glGetShaderiv : glGetProgramiv )( obj, isShader ? GL_COMPILE_STATUS : GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
    if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
    ( isShader ? glGetShaderInfoLog : glGetProgramInfoLog )( obj, sizeof( log ), NULL, (GLchar*)log );
    std::cerr << (GLchar*)log << "\n";
    std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
    glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
    glCompileShader( shader );
    CheckStatus( shader, true );
    glAttachShader( program, shader );
    glDeleteShader( shader );
}

const char* const vert = 1 + R"GLSL(
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
void main()
{
   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);
};
)GLSL";

const char* const frag = 1 + R"GLSL(
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
void main()
{
   FragColor = vec4(0.8f, 0.3f, 0.02f, 1.0f);
}
)GLSL";

int main(void)
{
    glfwSetErrorCallback( []( int, const char* desc )
    {
        std::cerr << desc << "\n";
        std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    } );
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cout<<"GLFW failed to Initialize!"<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    GLfloat vertices[] =
    {
        -0.5f, -0.5f * float(sqrt(3)) / 3, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f * float(sqrt(3)) / 3, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.5f * float(sqrt(3)) * 2 / 3, 0.0f
    };

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Open GL", NULL, NULL);
    if(!window)
    {
        std::cout<<"Something went Wrong when Creating a Window!\nShutting down ..."<<std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    gladLoadGLLoader( (GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress );

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

    GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
    AttachShader( prog, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vert );
    AttachShader( prog, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag );
    glLinkProgram( prog );
    CheckStatus( prog, false );
    glUseProgram( prog );

    GLuint VAO;
    GLuint VBO;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(prog);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteProgram(prog);

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "The targeted version of macOS only supports forward-compatible core profile contexts for OpenGL 3.2 and above" I put 3.3 and used your code but that's what I get

Comment: @NickDeveloper: Sorry about that, forgot that macOS [needs](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR_hint) `GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT` set to `GLFW_TRUE` for Core contexts.  Updated.

Comment: Thank you for the answer it worked and I never thought is would thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Note that with a 3.3 core profile on MacOS you may also need to call `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);`
by GM at comment Section and genpfault